disable subdomain in proxy pass redirects
My main domain is https://example.com I decided to create blog section in another subdomain and due security issues in another server. with ProxyPass in Apache VirtualHost configuration I demonstrated https://blog.example.com/blog address as https://example.com/blog
main server ran nextjs application.
main server http-vhost.conf:
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    UserDir disabled
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias example.com
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /var/www/cgi-bin/
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/homedir.log homedir
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/access_log combined
    ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/error_log
    ProxyPreserveHost On

    ProxyPass   "/blog" https://blog.example.com/blog
    ProxyPassReverse "/blog" https://blog.example.com/blog

    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:3000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:3000/

    <Location "/blog">
        ProxyPreserveHost Off
        ProxyPassReverse "https://blog.example.com"
        ProxyErrorOverride On
    </Location>


</VirtualHost>

But unfortunately I can't disable this address https://blog.example.com/blog I wanna only show this address https://example.com/blog
Is there any way to do above job only with .htaccess in blog.example.com server?
blog.example.com ran wordpress server using shared host and i cannot configure httpd-vhost.conf and I only can modify .htaccess file

You don't show us any configuration or explain what the problem actually is.

I updated  my question

It's still not clear what happens and what you want to happen
